# How to make an animation listener in MonoDroid?

Tags: c#, .net, android, xamarin.android

I want to take this android code and convert it to monoDroid

```
Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this,
            QuizMenuActivity.class));
        QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

I have this so far

```
Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.Fade_in2);
 fade2.SetAnimationListener(????);
```

I don't see new AnimationListener(). It seems ot want some interface or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source Java code is making use of anonymous inner classes:

```
fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {...});
```

C# doesn't support these (C# 3 anonymous types are in no way similar to Java anonymous inner classes), so you need to provide an explicit type and use that instead:

```
class MyAnimationListener : Java.Lang.Object,
        Android.Views.Animations.Animation.IAnimationListener
{
    Activity self;

    public MyAnimation (Activity self)
    {
        this.self = self;
    }

    public void OnAnimationEnd (Animation animation)
    {
        self.StartActivity (new Intent (self, typeof (QuizMenuActivity)));
        self.Finish ();
    }

    public void OnAnimationRepeat (Animation animation)
    {
    }

    public void OnAnimationStart (Animation animation)
    {
    }
}

// ...
fade2.SetAnimationListener (new MyAnimationListener (this));
```

As seen above, to implement the interface we also inherit from [Java.Lang.Object](http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Architecture/Android_Callable_Wrappers#Implementing_Interfaces) (this implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject` for us), and instead of implicitly referencing `QuizSplashActivity.this` as is done in Java, we instead need to explicitly capture it as a `self` field.

This could be simplified by providing a helper base type (I imagine that in the Java code the `AnimationListener` is a helper type, as not all of the Animation.AnimationListener methods were provided, so doing the ~same thing in C# would work as well).