# How to use SetAnimationListener()?

Tags: animation, xamarin.android

I would like to know when my animation is finished, so I have to use an AnimationListener.

I cannot seem to find out how to do that in MonoDroid (C#).

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876538/how-to-make-an-animation-listener-in-monodroid/6932178#6932178

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short one I wrote to get me a callback when the animation ends:

```
class AnimationListenerEndCallback : Java.Lang.Object, Animation.IAnimationListener
{
    public delegate void Callback(Animation animation);
    private Callback callback;
    public AnimationListenerEndCallback(Callback callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void OnAnimationEnd(Android.Views.Animations.Animation animation)
    {
        callback(animation);
    }

    public void OnAnimationRepeat(Android.Views.Animations.Animation animation)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void OnAnimationStart(Android.Views.Animations.Animation animation)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.pull_up);
a.SetAnimationListener(new AnimationListenerEndCallback(delegate
{
   // all your local variables are still in scope, so you
   // can use them here
}));
```