# ExpandableListView Child Events

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to detect and handle the selection of a child in an ExpandableListView.  But none of the event handlers or listeners I've tried ever seem to fire.  Which one am I to use?  I've tried:

```
lv.Click += HandleSelect
```

and

```
lv.ItemClick += HandleSelect
```

and

```
lv.ChildClick += HandleSelect
```

and

```
lv.ItemSelected += HandleSelect
```

and

```
lv.SetOnChildClickListener(new ChildClick)
```

HandleSelect Event Handler

```
void HandleSelect(Object o, EventArgs e)
{
   var obj = o;  //Breakpoint set here and it never breaks for any of the above;
}
```

ChildClick listener

```
class ChildClick : ExpandableListView.IOnChildClickListener
{
 public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public IntPtr Handle
        {
            get { return new IntPtr(0); }
        }

        public bool OnChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View clickedView, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {
            var clicked = clickedView; //Breakpoint set here, never breaks;
            return true;
        }
}
```

Here is the BaseExpandableListAdapter I am using to populate the ExpandableListView

```
 class MarketAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private readonly string[] _stores;
    private readonly List<string> _storeList = new List<string>();
    private readonly List<List<Call>> _calls = new List<List<Call>>(); 

    public MarketAdapter(Context context, IEnumerable<Call> calls)
    {
        _context = context;

        List<Call> marketCalls =
            (from c in calls
             where c.InProgress == "0"
             select new Call() {CallNumber = c.CallNumber, ServiceType = c.ServiceType, Priority = c.Priority, Address = c.Address, City = c.City, Contact = c.Contact, Description = c.Description, Phone = c.Phone, Site = c.Site, State = c.State}).ToList();

        foreach (IGrouping<string, Call> stores in marketCalls.GroupBy(s => s.Site))
        {                
            _storeList.Add(stores.Key + "," + stores.First().City + "," + stores.First().State);
            List<List<Call>> callgroup = new List<List<Call>>();
            List<Call> call = new List<Call>(from c in stores select new Call() {CallNumber = c.CallNumber, ServiceType = c.ServiceType, Priority = c.Priority, Description = c.Description});
            callgroup.Add(call);
            _calls.Add(call);
        }
        _stores = _storeList.ToArray();
    }

    public override Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return _calls.ElementAt(groupPosition).Count;
    }

    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        List<Call> callList = _calls.ElementAt(groupPosition);
        Call _call = callList.ElementAt(childPosition);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listviewchild, null);
        }

        TextView call = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.Call);
        call.Text = _call.CallNumber;
        TextView type = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.Type);
        type.Text = _call.ServiceType;
        TextView priority = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.Priority);
        priority.Text = _call.Priority;
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.Description);
        description.Text = _call.Description;

        return convertView;
    }

    public override Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return _stores[groupPosition];
    }

    public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        string[] info = _stores[groupPosition].Split(new [] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string _site = info[0];
        string _city = info[1];
        string _state = info[2];

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listviewparent, null);
        }

        TextView site = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.Site);
        site.Text = _site;
        TextView city = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.City);
        city.Text = _city;
        TextView state = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.State);
        state.Text = _state;

        return convertView;
    }

    public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override int GroupCount
    {
        get { return _stores.Length; }
    }

    public override bool HasStableIds
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also just tried the solution explained here [OnChildClick inside ExpandableListActivity does not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546200/onchildclick-inside-expandablelistactivity-does-not-fire?rq=1) by setting the Layout and all of my TextViews focusable attrubute to false in listviewchild.axml but it still doesn't fire the listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed

```
void HandleSelect(Object o, EventArgs e)
{
  //do something
}
```

to

```
void HandleSelect(object o, ExpandableListView.ChildClickEventArgs e)
{
  //do something
}
```

and it is working.

Comment: I am having hard time implementing ExpandableListView onClick in Xamarin.Android, did you use : SetOnChildClickListener?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `onChildClickListener`, but you need to call it from the ExpandableListView class, like this:

```
lv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)  
        }); 
}
```

Comment: ChildClick is an ExpandableListView.IOnChildClickListener.

Comment: Never said it wasn't.  But, my answer works for me, so give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: That syntax doesn't work in MonoDroid.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876538/how-to-make-an-animation-listener-in-monodroid

Comment: Really?  Wow.  I wouldn't use something that causes documented Android framework functions to not work.  Good luck!

Comment: Got the ChildClick event to work.  Still not sure why the listener would never fire though.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Sorry I wasn't able to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.

In my listviewchild I had the xml attribute:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Which silently consumed the event. Removing the attribute enabled the ChildClick Eventhandler.